# Hasura Relay - How to work with Base64 encoded id's?

Tags: relay, hasura

I'm confused how to work with base64 encoded id's when using Hasura's relay endpoint.  My first problem came when trying to initialize a dropdown combo-box component to set the "option value" to be equal to the foreign key of related table (see image, below).  My next problem is how to pass IDs into parameterized queries (so I can retrieve details for an order with given "id").  Since all of these identifiers are base64 encoded it's not easy to do and I'm sure I must be missing something in my understanding.

Are these id's encoded specifically as warning that we should not be relying upon or using them in our code at all or are we supposed to be decoding them and using them for things like pagination, parameterized queries and combo-boxes, etc? Would appreciate some help to understand.

Here is example of my trouble with combo-box:  [Base64 Mangled Combo-box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi3QJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think perhaps with latest version of Hasura, we can now get at the database id.  The base64 encoded id when decoded is a array, so we can now get the database id by referencing array index 3 as in example below.

```
    const encodedHasuraRelayID = "WzEsICJsaWZlcGxhbiIsICJzdGF0dXNfcGxhbl9oZWFkZXIiLCAxXQ=="
    const decodedRelayID = atob(encodedHasuraRelayID)
    const relayIdAsArray = eval(decodedRelayID)
    const actualDatabaseID = relayIdAsArray[3]
    
    console.log(decodedRelayID)    // "[1, \"lifeplan\", \"status_plan_header\", 1]"
    console.log(relayIdAsArray)    // [1, "lifeplan", "status_plan_header", 1] 
    console.log(actualDatabaseID)  // 1  (the actual database ID)!
```

This appears to work though I've read elsewhere that using eval() in javascript is evil, so if someone knows a better way to convert from "decodedRelayID" to "relayIdAsArray", please let me know.

[Discussion of ObjectID Resolution in Relay](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1061)

Comment: Update1:  I also learned that if you name your database column something other than "id" (like "pk" perhaps), then Hasura will still use the token "id" when it creates its base64 encoded  "relayId" and queries that specify "pk" will return the actual database value without base64 encoding.  Also, if you're dealing with a legacy database that has used "id" for primary key and you can't change it, hasura has a config option now that you can use to control the name of the field for gql purposes for which you could change it to something like "pk" and get the same behavior.

Comment: Instead of eval(), you can just JSON.parse(). How to construct this base64 id? I tried bota(JSON.stringgy([])) the same value, but the result is different, what am I missing here?

Comment: @AlbertGao did you manage to build the id by yourself?

Comment: Ye, I did. You just need to btoa() your string, the hard part is, you have to add space between items, because that is how Hasura did it